# basic Linux bash command clarifications: awk and others

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, awk

I am using `Mac OS` and `Bash terminal` to do some basic scripting.
I have some questions which I could not find answers when I searched online
(or may be my search keywords were bad)

Firstly, I see there are three paths: `/bin, /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin`. some commands like `grep` are found in `/usr/bin`, while some others like `ls` are found in `/bin`.

why we have three different bins and what criteria goes to put commands like these over there

Secondly, I want to know the difference between using `'` and `.

```
echo `date` 
Fri Jan 10 10:36:52 PST 2014

awk '{print $1}' test.txt
1
2
3
4
```

if I try:

```
awk `{print $1}` test.txt 
-bash: {print: command not found
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
     >>> test. <<< txt
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

so when to use `'` and `.

Lastly, the above `awk with print` works. but this does not work

```
awk '{echo $1}' test.txt
```

can `print` and `echo` not be used interchangebly?

P.S: I am a beginner with `bash scripting`, please be kind

Comment: One question per post, please

Comment: @chepner: since they are very related, I thought having them in one could be useful for other beginners too.

Comment: @eagertoLearn they are only related in as much as you want to know the answers to both questions. Aside from that, they are completely unrelated.

Comment: @EdMorton: Although they are not related, I learned a couple of things and I guess thats what SO is all about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brief answers not necessarily exhaustive:

1. /bin is usually for system commands
2. /usr/bin is for commands for users
3. /usr/local/bin is for software not typically installed by a distribution or release of an OS.

Quotes:

1. Things in single quotes are not touched by the shell
2. Things in double quotes are variable expanded by the shell ($var is expanded to what $var contains)
3. Things in back quotes are executed as a command and the output of that command replaces what was in the back quotes.  You can also use `$(echo Hello)` to achieve the same thing.

You cannot easily mix awk and shell inside a string passed as a script to awk. (ex: `awk '{echo $1}' test.txt`)

Comment: `$(echo hello)` did not work? when I do `$(echo hello)`, I get 
`hello: command not found`

Comment: Remember what is said earlier about back quotes.  The command(s) in back quotes are executed and then the output replaces what was in the back quotes.  To get what I think you're looking for, you'd have to do `echo $(echo hello)` otherwise the shell will try to execute the result of the back quoted command as a command.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk `{print $1}` test.txt
```

This fail since you are using back tics and not single quotes.
Correct:

```
awk '{print $1}' test.txt
```

It will then print first field of all line in the file.

---

```
awk '{echo $1}' test.txt
```

Does not work since `echo` is not an `awk` command.

Tell us what text you have and what you like to get out of it..

Answer (score 0):

You need to read a book. I recommend `Shell Scripting Recipes: A Problem-Solution Approach` ([http://www.amazon.com/Shell-Scripting-Recipes-Problem-Solution-Approach/dp/1590594711](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590594711)). Read it, work through the exercises, and then come back with questions if you have any (or even better ask them at the comp.unix.shell newsgroup where that book's author and all the other shell experts hang out).

Answer (score 0):

`print` is an awk command.

`echo` is a shell command.

backticks and `$()` run shell commands.

`'` quotes the contents such that the shell does not expand anything inside them.

Answer (score 0):

`$(echo hello)` is the same as: `echo hello`. By doing this you ask the bash interpreter to execute the result of that command which is "hello". But hello is not a command (unless if you define it yourself).

These examples are all correct:

```
foo=$(echo hello)
echo ${foo}

foo=(echo "echo hello")
${foo}
```